# How to check whether a user has already signed up using Phone Number before send otp

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

check phone number whether it exist if exist error and check before otp

```
 signIn() {
this.setState({ waiting: true });
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithPhoneNumber(this.state.phoneNumber)
  //if phone number is right, then update phone in store and call verify code screen
  .then(res => {
    Store.currentUserPhone = this.state.phoneNumber;
    Actions.VerifyCode({ result: res });
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message, waiting: false 
 }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the user auth object whether there's a phoneNumber value with

```
const userAuth = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if(userAuth.phoneNumber !== undefined) {
   //user has phone number 
}else {
   //user does not have phone number
}
```

Comment: can you please tell where i can define it?

Comment: I am using rnfirebase for my app, you can check with this link here https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/phone-auth#Full-Example